# I am unable to call Json array list inside json arrray

Tags: java, android

```
JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("products");
List<Actors.Image1> shi22=new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

    Actors actor = new Actors();

    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
         actor.setDescription(object.getString("short_description"));

    List<Actors.Image1> image1List1=new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray getImage1=object.getJSONArray("images");
    for (int j=0;j<getImage1.length();j++) {
        Actors.Image1 boom = new Actors.Image1();
        JSONObject lastObject = getImage1.getJSONObject(j);
        boom.setAttachment(lastObject.getString("attachment"));
        image1List1.add(boom);

    }
    shi22.add(image1List1);
}
```

is this loop correct or not ????

This is Model Class

```
public class Actors {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Image1> image1List;



    public Actors() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Actors(String name, String description,  List <Image1> image1List) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
             this.image1List = image1List;
    }


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

in image class have attached some Base64 strings file ....in this array loop is not working properly kindly suggest me loop

Comment: Please be more specific as to where exactly in the code is your problem.

Comment: Impossible to say if the loop is correct when you haven't told us either what it's supposed to do or what it's doing.

Comment: IntelliData@ i am facing problem in loop ....